# Can some one show me how you do this kind of problem by Frobenius?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have a homework need to due with Frobenius method. However I was sick on the that we covered that in class so I don't know how to do this problem. Can someone show me all the process the way you do?

The question is

> $x=0$ is a regular singular point of the given differential equation    $$xy"+(x+1)y'-\frac{y}{9x}=0.$$
>   Use the method of Frobenius to obtain two linearly independent series solutions about $x=0$. You must show at least $4$ nonzero terms of each series solutions.

Please help me!

Comment: Have you tried reading wikipedia pages, etc. about the Frobenius method?  Where did you get stuck?  If you don't tell us where you are blocked, we would just be working out another example and you still wouldn't understand the method.

Comment: @ErickWong [![I just did until here and I don't know if it correct or not][1]][1]     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4XTx.jpg

Comment: @Bryan Great details, if you add what you can to the question I think it would help a lot.

Comment: @ErickWong since I didn't make to class during the day my professor covered that stuff. I have no clue what to continue next. Can you show me how?

Answer (score 1):

Your second line $y'' + (x+1)y' - \frac19 y = 0$ does not make sense: it should be $y'' + \frac{x+1}{x} y' - \frac1{9x^2} y = 0$ which is obtained by dividing the first line through by $x$ in order to make the coefficient of $y''$ equal to $1$.  Nevertheless, you did extract the correct functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, so it doesn't invalidate the remainder.

You appear to have solved the indicial equation correctly to obtain the roots $r=\pm\frac13$.  Now all that's left to do is to actually look for the series solutions one term at a time.  I'll just work out a couple terms of the case $r=\frac13$ and I think you should have no trouble doing the rest.

We are looking for a solution of the form $$y(x) = a_0 x^{1/3} + a_1 x^{4/3} + a_2 x^{7/3} + \cdots.$$  Substituting this into the original equation (or the second line, once you've corrected it) gives:

$$\begin{align} xy'' = x \big(- \frac29 a_0 x^{-5/3} + \frac49 a_1 x^{-2/3} + \cdots\big) &= -\frac29 a_0 x^{-2/3} + \frac49 a_1 x^{1/3} + \cdots \\
(x+1)y' = (x+1) \big(\frac13 a_0 x^{-2/3} + \frac43 a_1 x^{1/3} + \cdots\big) &= \frac13 a_0 x^{-2/3} + (\frac13 a_0 + \frac43 a_1) x^{1/3} + \cdots \\
-\frac{y}{9x} &= -\frac19 a_0 x^{-2/3} - \frac19 a_1 x^{1/3} + \cdots.
\end{align}$$

Summing these three terms should give a series with all $0$ terms, so we have the constraints:

$$\begin{align} -\frac29 a_0 + \frac13 a_0 - \frac19 a_0 &= 0 \\
  \frac49 a_1 + \frac13 a_0 + \frac43 a_1 - \frac19 a_1 &= 0.\end{align}$$

The first of these simplifies to $0 = 0$, which is as expected since it just verifies that the indicial equation was solved correctly: since this is a linear equation the leading coefficient $a_0$ can typically be arbitrary, since we can multiply everything by a constant. The second constraint simplifies to something more concrete:

$$\frac23 a_0 + \frac43 a_1 = 0 \implies a_1 = -\frac12 a_0.$$

So the series solution for $r=\frac13$ starts as $a_0 \big( x^{1/3} - \frac12  x^{4/3} + \cdots\big) $.

This illustrates the basic idea of Frobenius's method, and it should be clear how you can keep going to higher-order terms to extract the relations between $a_2$ and $a_1$, etc.  For your first attempt I would suggest doing it this long way to understand what's going on.

Once you are confident you can "automate" the process somewhat by computing the derivatives in a more generic way for $a_k x^{1/3 + k}$ and then you can deduce a general equation that relates $a_{k+1}$ to $a_k$, and thereby find the general form of the series.  But since this question only asks for the first 4 terms, you may find it simpler to work with $a_2, a_3, a_4$ explicitly as above.